# Create new repository, fork, or clone in Github?

Tags: github

A couple years ago I created a C# program for one of my classes. We had to work in groups and used GitHub. Now that I finally graduated I'm trying to add some code to my GitHub account to show to prospective employers, I realized that that program is not in my repositories (another teammate created it, but I contributed). Also, we have a lot of useless files in that repository and everything is a mess, it doesn't even has a Read Me.

So, my question is: should I create another repository without the useless files and cleaner code? Or should I fork the repository? What would be the best way to add it to my profile?

Also, what book, video, website, etc. would you recommend to learn how to use GitHub fast?

Comment: Both questions are off-topic here: the first is primarily opinion-based and the second asks us to find or recommend an off-site resource. You can read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you fork the repository people will see that you forked from a repository and there will be a history of commits made by whoever committed into that repository.

Assuming that it is not a very large code base, why don't you just create a new repository and just start doing the project again in a progressive manner where you can demonstrated your skills on the project. I am assuming as you already done the project early it will be easier for you to create the project ground up and will give you a chance to improve the previous code along the way.

you can find lots of git hub tutorials for beginners if you just search on google.

[try git](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1)

I find this is very useful [git scm](https://git-scm.com)

[git for begginers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ugN-IYV1NTM)